# Simple Phonebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

this is some simple code I wrote for a phonebook.
It does not seem to work though, and I do not know why. 
I am very new to python, and I am sure there are many errors.

```
def startup(contactlist = {}):
    print "Welcome to Contacts+\n"
    print "Please enter your name"
    name = raw_input()
    print "Hi " + name + " would you like to check your existing contacts or make    new ones?"
    print "To make new contacts type in 'New'"
    print "To check existing contacts type in 'Contacts'"
    choose = ""
    choose = raw_input()
        if choose == "'New'" or choose == "'new'" or choose == "New" or choose == "new":
            newcontact()
        elif choose == "'Contacts'" or choose == "'contacts'" or choose == "Contacts" or choose == "contacts":
            checkcontact()

def newcontact():
    startup(contactlist = {})
    print "To create a new contact please first input the name"
    contactname = raw_input()
    print "Next enter the phone number"
    contactnumber = raw_input()
    print "Contact created!"
    contactlist[name] = number

def checkcontact():
    startup(contactlist = {})
    print contactlist

startup()
```

Comment: two tips: 1) always end `if ... elif ...` clauses with `else`, even if it should be just `pass`, to make sure you covered all paths; 2) instead of list you may consider using dictionary (`dict`) for contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run this...?

This if/elif statement shouldn't be indented:

```
        if choose == "'New'" or choose == "'new'" or choose == "New" or choose == "new":
            newcontact()
        elif choose == "'Contacts'" or choose == "'contacts'" or choose == "Contacts" or choose == "contacts":
            checkcontact()
```

And why do you have:

```
startup(contactlist = {})
```

in the beginning of newcontact() and checkcontact() function?

Comment: I have that so it is a variable that I can use in every function

Comment: That's not the syntax to pass in a variable. That's calling the `contactlist` param as a keyword argument and setting it equal to the empty dict!

Answer (score 0):

Four things you can do *right now* to make your code better:

- Go read about [this gotcha](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/) in Python. We tricked you. (We're sorry! We had good reasons.) You can't really do that with lists and dicts, and you have to use a Python idiom involving `None` to do it right.
- Use `raw_input`'s first argument. Instead of `print('Hey user!'); raw_input()`, just write `raw_input('Hey user!')`.
- Learn the `in` keyword. Whenever you find yourself saying `if x == 'x' or x == 'y' or x == 'z'`, it's probably easier to write `if x in 'xyz'` (strings are iterable, remember?). You can also get rid of two of those cases by stripping off quotes the user might enter if you don't want them -- `choose.strip("'")`.
- Fix your function calls. Functions in Python can be called in two ways, using positional arguments `f(a, b, c)` or keyword arguments `f(a, b=0, c=2)`. Calls like `startup(contactlist={})` are just explicitly setting that argument to the empty dict, its default value, so this is always equivalent to `startup()` the way you have it defined.